# Is width mandatory for the parent container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, styles

I have a parent div with three inner child divs as below.

```
<div style="width:900px;">
   <div style="width:300px;">somedata</div>
   <div style="width:300px;">somedata</div>
   <div style="width:300px;">somedata</div>
</div>
```

In which case (like cross browser) it is mandatory to specify width for the parent container(900px in this case)? I need a scenario where we actually give width for the parent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the scenario is when you want it to be exactly `900px` wide, no more growing or shrinking.

Comment: What possible reasons there might be for making the setting *mandatory*? As per which authority or compelling reason? You must be thinking of a specific case that is essentially more complicated than the one presented (where the width setting has no effect except that it makes minimum width of the page 900px and may therefore cause horizontal scroll bar that would not otherwise appear).

Comment: Thats correct. Someone has put the parent width into the code and I'm going to remove that. Before removing I want to know is there any situation where we actually need it.

Comment: Just be aware that removing the width declaration will automatically make the 100% of it's own parent. Also, if you wanted that div centered (perhaps with auto margins) it might break that too.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the parent container width when you use percentage width for the child elements.
otherwise it will just occupy the required width